# Minhas matrizes não aparecem na tela em C

Tags: c, matriz, jogos

Preciso fazer um jogo da memória e estou na primeira parte dele, em que é preciso criar um tabuleiro nulo e depois distribuir pares de números em posições aleatórias. O que eu fiz é dar ao usuário 3 opções: jogo fácil, médio ou difícil. O meu problema é que para as opções médio e difícil o programa só mostra a matriz nula, sem mostrar a matriz posterior com os valores distribuídos.

```
#include <stdio.h>  // Biblioteca para printf e scanf
#include <stdlib.h> //Biblioteca para o rand()
#include <time.h> // Biblioteca para srand(time(null))

int nivel;
int a, b;
int i, j;
int Matr[4][4];
int count1, count2 = 0;
int x, y;
int num = 0;
int count16 = 0; 


int main(){

printf("Escolha o nível do jogo, digite:\n 1 para fácil\n 2 para médio\n 3 para dificil\n");
scanf("%d", &nivel);


//----------------------NÍVEL FÁCIL NÍVEL FÁCIL NÍVEL FÁCIL--------------------------------------
    
if (nivel == 1){
        for (i=0; i<4; i++)                              //Inicio da parte fácil
            for(j=0; j<4; j++)
            Matr[i][j] = 0;    

    
        for (i=0; i<4; i++){                         //Essa parte mostra o tabuleiro para o usuário
            for(j=0; j<4; j++)
            printf("%3d", Matr[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
                }   
            while(num<9){

            int count16 = 0;                               
            srand(time(NULL));                            
                while (count16 < 2){
                    x = rand() %4;
                    y = rand() %4;
                        if(Matr[x][y] == 0){
                            Matr[x][y] = num;
                            count16++;
                        }   
                    } 
                    num++;
                }
        for (x=0; x<4; x++){                         //Essa parte mostra o tabuleiro para o usuário
            for(y=0; y<4; y++){
                printf("%3d\t", Matr[x][y]);
                
            }
            printf("\n");
    }   }
    
//----------------------NÍVEL FÁCIL NÍVEL FÁCIL NÍVEL FÁCIL--------------------------------------
//----------------------NÍVEL MÉDIO NÍVEL MÉDIO NÍVEL MÉDIO--------------------------------------
else if (nivel == 2){
        for (i=0; i<6; i++)                              //Criação de uma matriz nula 6x6
            for(j=0; j<6; j++)
            Matr[i][j] = 0;
            
        for (i=0; i<6; i++){                         //Essa parte mostra o tabuleiro para o usuário
            for(j=0; j<6; j++)
            printf("%3d", Matr[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
    }
    
while(num<19){
        int count16 = 0;                               
        srand(time(NULL));                            
            while (count16 < 2){
                x = rand() %6;
                y = rand() %6;
                    if(Matr[x][y] == 0){
                        Matr[x][y] = num;
                        count16++;
                    }   
            }
        num++;
}

for (x=0; x<6; x++){                         //Essa parte mostra o tabuleiro para o usuário
            for(y=0; y<6; y++){
                printf("%3d\t", Matr[x][y]);    
            }
    printf("\n");
        }
    }
//---------------------NÍVEL MÉDIO NÍVEL MÉDIO NÍVEL MÉDIO--------------------------------------
//---------------------NÍVEL DIFÍCIL NÍVEL DIFÍCIL----------------------------------------------
    else{
    
        for (i=0; i<8; i++)                              //Criação de uma matriz nula 6x6
            for(j=0; j<8; j++)
            Matr[i][j] = 0;
            
        for (i=0; i<8; i++){                         //Essa parte mostra o tabuleiro para o usuário
            for(j=0; j<8; j++)
            printf("%3d", Matr[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
}
int num = 0;
while(num<33){

int count16 = 0;                               
srand(time(NULL));                            
while (count16 < 2){
    x = rand() %8;
    y = rand() %8;
    if(Matr[x][y] == 0){
        Matr[x][y] = num;
        count16++;
        }   
}
num++;
}
for (x=0; x<8; x++){                         //Essa parte mostra o tabuleiro para o usuário
            for(y=0; y<8; y++){
                printf("%3d\t", Matr[x][y]);
                
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
}
    
//------------------------NÍVEL DIFÍCIL NÍVEL DIFÍCIL----------------------------------------   
}
```

Comment: Se você declara sua matriz como [4][4] como quer utilizar como [6][6]no nível médio ou [8][8] no nível difícil?

Comment: Verdade, obrigado por apontar isso. Vou tentar dividir o código em funções com uma pra cada nível e definir uma matriz diferente pra cada.

Comment: Uma possibilidade é você trocar suas variáveis globais, não recomendada na maioria dos casos, por declarações locais em cada um dos blocos ou mesmo fazer alocação dinâmica da matriz.